# Проблемы с синтаксисом While + SQL

Tags: python, sql

*Обучаюсь работать с субд*

```
orders_id = 2,3
count = 0
while count < 2:
    orders_list = "INSERT INTO orders(user_id,item_id) VALUES(%s, %s)"
    val = [(1, orders_id)]
    mycursor.executemany(orders_list,val)
    mydb.commit()
    count +=1
```

Как мне сделать так что бы цикл брал по значению из order_id и пихал в val?

при этом если использовать любые скобки в order_id ошибка типа

Python 'tuple' cannot be converted to a MySQL type

Comment: Покажите полный CREATE TABLE таблицы. `user_id` - первичный автоинкрементный ключ? *Как мне сделать так что бы цикл брал по значению из order_id и пихал в val?* Сделать для этого отдельный цикл. Например.

Answer (score 0):

```
orders_id = 2
count = 0
while count < 2 and orders_id < 4:
    orders_list = "INSERT INTO orders(user_id,item_id) VALUES(%s, %s)"
    val = [(1, orders_id)]
    mycursor.executemany(orders_list,val)
    mydb.commit()
    count +=1
    orders_id +=1
```

только таким образом походу

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Не добавляйте факты как ответы - дополняйте текст вопроса. За исключением самоответа (но сейчас явно не этот случай).